# How do I go about graphing the region, $\Re(z^2)>1$ in the Complex Plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The questions asks to describe the region, $\Re(z^2)>1$, graphically in the complex plane. The math is fairly simple. If we let $z=x+iy$, then $z^2=(x+iy)(x+iy)\\z^2=x^2-y^2+i(2xy)$

Hence the $\Re(z^2)=x^2-y^2>1$

Graphically speaking, this function sketches a hyperbola in the real $xy$ plane. However, my confusion is that the question asks to represent $\Re(z^2)>1$ in the complex plane. How can I go about representing the real part of a function in the complex plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a set, the complex plane is the same as $\mathbb{R}^2$. Your region is the "exterior" of the unit hyperbola" ( to the right of the right branch and to the left of the left one).